# Getting completion feature with Alt+F2 in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, auto-completion

I know there is an application that does what I want. It's called

`gmrun`

But I was wondering if I could get something like bash completion with unity's run interface .i.e. with tab command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work with current Unity (as you already found out).

However, if you post your idea to http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ or present it on the [Ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana), some developer might implement it (however, don't count on it landing in Natty).

Comment: you could add that he can report a wishlist bug on launchpad as well ^^

Answer (score 3):

Submit a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-place-applications/+filebug) against `unity-place-applications`as that is a wishlist item. There is currently no option in Unity for tab auto-completion to work on the Alt+F2 screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in 11.04.

Hopefully the whole of Alt+F2 in the Dash will be refined over the next few releases, because at the moment it is lacking compared to the old version.

See also [Bug #736222: cannot paste into dash](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/736222).