# How enable tab-completion in Dash to run commands?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, auto-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting completion feature with Alt+F2 in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34671/getting-completion-feature-with-altf2-in-unity)

In stardard gnome when I do Alt+F2 I can complete paths and commands with Tab but now in Unity the focus moves down to choose something else.
Is there any way to enable this feature?