# How can I use tab completion in the 'Run a command' box?

Tags: unity, 11.04, auto-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting completion feature with Alt+F2 in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34671/getting-completion-feature-with-altf2-in-unity)

I finally upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 and so far, I am liking the experience.

The only thing I have a problem with, is:

- While in the execute dialog, I can't complete the path with <kbd>Tab</kbd> like I could do in 10.10

Is anybody having any fix for this?

Comment: Does it help if you log out and choose the Ubuntu Classic session before logging back in? It will give you a GNOME2 interface like in 10.10 (no Unity), but it could be a temporary fix.

Comment: Yes, it works. It does give me the classic Gnome2 interface. but this is surely not a solution :-/

Comment: This is what I was thinking about, to split them, but somehow I wrote them into one. Sorry. I just try `appmenu-gtk`

Comment: One more unusual thing found. When I drag a document to the launcher, it only highlights the programs that can open it, but what about the case when I have to drop it somewhere else? like in my thinderbird or GMail, to attach in in the mail? this is bad.

Comment: @Jorge I just did that. I hope it looks fine now.

Comment: @Sheikh Thanks, and don't worry about keeping around the crossed-out material. The most important thing is to maintain a well-presented question, and it's okay to do so at the expense of losing some of the history of this page. *[Edit, edit, edit](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work/542#542)*, they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any solution to this.. as a result, got used to with the default Unity behavior :-/

Answer (score -2):

Well, Natty is different and making something different may result in bugs.
Crashes might happen. For the top bar a restart (re-log-in) usually helps.
I didn't have many problems with Unity.

Comment: I've restarted the system several times, as a part of my regular routine, but that didn't help.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that unity may not be quite ready for prime time yet.  I have experienced similar issues and I think the simplest fix for now may be to disable unity and revisit in a month or two.