# Unity not working correctly after using `unity --reset`

Tags: 11.04, unity

I recently had crashed unity which I recovered using command unity --reset. I don't know what triggered this, but now I can't see the menu-bar of my applications lying in the top panel, rather, they are now integrated with the application, so like 10.10 and unlike 11.04
Is anybody having any fix for this?

(segregated from [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/47766/15992) question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to work, but you might just give it a try:

```
metacity --replace
```

If that doesn't work, try choosing 'Ubuntu Classic' down in the login screen, do a little browsing, log out or restart, then choose 'Ubuntu' again.

It might just work.

Good luck

Comment: I'll try that out, still, it "might" work :P

Answer (score 0):

"unity --replace" is a risky command to run in the Terminal, because if you ever close the terminal, Ubuntu reverts to a state as you described. If you want to implement changes in Unity, it is safer to log out and then log back in. If you must use "unity --replace", it is better to run it in the Dash (use Alt+F2 to bring up the run dialogue).