# How can I get a more traditional drop-down like menu for Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I can't find a drop-down like 10.10 where I could list all the applications/menu. I understand that the launcher is there for it now, but somehow, I currently feel that I was more comfortable with the drop-down menus.

Any fix for this one?

(segregated from [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/47766/15992) question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can select **"Classic Ubuntu"**
  environment at the *log-in screen* if
  you prefer classic Ubuntu.
- **Optionally**, you can get this classic
  menu indicator: [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/classicmenu-indicator-puts-old-school-gnome-menus-in-unity/)

*However, my personal suggestion is to try to get used to it. I didn't like it at first too, but now I love it.*

Comment: Nice idea, but I just want to have it handy in case I need it

Comment: The "Classic" option [will be dropped](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/739812/comments/5) in October, so it's only a short-term solution.

Comment: Surely you would be able to install it through Software Center? It will just not be available on the CD afaik.

Answer (score 10):

[Cardapio](https://launchpad.net/cardapio) is a nice middle-ground between the old and new interfaces:

[image: Cardapio from Web Upd8]

This [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I1OrazNB0o) shows it in action. The [custom launcher available from Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/use-classic-menu-in-unity-classicmenu.html) makes it quite convenient to use.

It's currently only available from a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cardapio
```

Answer (score 5):

Run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the Applications icon in the launcher, then you'll get a list of categories like you did in the Applications menu in Gnome-panel. If you select a category, then you'll get a lense with only the applications in that category. You can get the same list of categories if you just click it too. There is a drop down menu on the right of the search field.

Comment: Yes, its there, but I think It'll be dropped soon. see the comments on the question..

Answer (score 1):

If Cardapio fails to launch for you in 11.10 you may have to also use

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

per the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/cardapio/+bug/878219

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get a 'menu' of sorts with the Dash. Click on the Ubuntu logo to get the dash, click on 'More Apps', in the top right corner of the dash, there is a drop down menu, allowing you to filter by category of apps (accessories, games, ...)